# Getting Exception while trying to parse JSON Object from AJAX call to Java

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, struts2

**

Updated Code

**

**My Javascript/Ajax Code:**

```
$(function() {
        $("#create_obd").bind("click", function(event) {

            var soNumber = [];

             $('#sales_order_lineItems input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function(index) { 

               var row = $(this).parent().parent();
               var rowcells = row.find('td');

                var soRowData = {
                       so_number:rowcells[1].innerText
                    };
               soNumber.push(soRowData);

             }); //loop ends

            var soNumbers = JSON.stringify(soNumber);
            alert(soNumbers);
             $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: server_ip_address + "/createobdaction",
                    data: soNumbers,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data){alert(data);},
                    failure: function(errMsg) {
                        alert(errMsg);
                    }
                });
            });
    });
```

**My Java Code:**

```
package com.app.action;

import java.util.List;

import com.app.bean.SONumber;

public class CreateOBDAction {

private List<SONumber> soNumbers;

public String createOBD() {
    System.out.println(soNumbers.size());
    return "jsonCreateOBDSuccess";
}

public List<SONumber> getSoNumbers() {
    System.out.println("Getter................");
    return soNumbers;
}

public void setSoNumbers(List<SONumber> soNumbers) {
    System.out.println("Setter............");
    this.soNumbers = soNumbers;
}

}
```

**Bean Class**

```
package com.app.bean;

public class SONumber {

    String soNumber;

    public String getSoNumber() {
        return soNumber;
    }

    public void setSoNumber(String soNumber) {
        this.soNumber = soNumber;
    }
}
```

**Struts.xml**

```
<action name="createobdaction" class="com.app.action.CreateOBDAction" 
      method="createOBD">
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="json">
        <param name="enableSMD">true</param>
    </interceptor-ref>       
    <result name="jsonCreateOBDSuccess" type="json" />
</action>
```

**Exception**

> 15:32:00,092 ERROR JSONInterceptor:34 - Unable to deserialize JSON
>   object from request 15:32:00,093 DEBUG Dispatcher:80 - Exception
>   occurred during processing request: Unable to deserialize JSON object
>   from request org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: Unable to
>   deserialize JSON object from request  at
>   org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor.intercept(JSONInterceptor.java:117)

Answer (score 0):

- Include the [`Struts2-JSON-plugin`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/json-plugin.html) in your project;
- create properties, getters and setters for each field of the JSONized object coming from the page;
- add the JSON Interceptor to the Interceptor Stack used by your action.
- That's it.

From the docs:

> If the interceptor is used, the action will be populated from the JSON content in the request, these are the rules of the interceptor:
>
> 1. The "content-type" must be "application/json"
> 2. The JSON content must be
>      well formed, see json.org for grammar.
> 3. Action must have a public
>      "setter" method for fields that must be populated.
> 4. Supported types for
>      population are: Primitives (int,long...String), Date, List, Map,
>      Primitive Arrays, Other class (more on this later), and Array of Other
>      class.
> 5. Any object in JSON, that is to be populated inside a list, or a
>      map, will be of type Map (mapping from properties to values), any
>      whole number will be of type Long, any decimal number will be of type
>      Double, and any array of type List.

Comment: Thanks Andrea for your reply. Could you please help me to understand this a little better. Actually, I am very new on this and so, may be asking very basics.
I have included these three in my Action class. 
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
What else I require for the plugin?

Comment: Included getter/setter also in my Action class. Updated the above code.

Comment: Try making your SONumber class a standard class, not an inner class

Comment: Did that. Now getting InstantiationException

Comment: Please update your answer with the new code and the full exception

Comment: Changed a little in the code and now getting JSON Exception.Updated the question with latest code. Waiting for your reply.

Comment: Your object is not a valid JSON Object. Take a look at source code, it needs to be a map: http://jsonplugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/main/java/com/googlecode/jsonplugin/JSONInterceptor.java. Take the code from your alert(SoNumbers) and validate it here: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Got Valid JSON after putting the alert message in the JSON validator. I am testing with only one data and here is the JSON getting created in my code. [{"so_number":"12345"}]

Comment: @minchi Try changing **data: soNumbers,** to **data: {"soNumbers" : soNumbers},**.